# Sed command add '#' in front of line

Tags: unix, sed

I want to add `#` to comment out lines in a file using `sed`, however I do not want to add a `#` in front of every line, just after a specific pattern. How should I go about this?

Comment: You should check stack-exchange to see if your questions have already been answered. This one seems to have been already: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336768/insert-character-in-the-beginning-of-specified-line-in-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has probably been answered before. But to do it **in place**

```
sed -i '' 's/your_line_pattern/#&/g' file
```

You can also output this into a new file by:

```
sed 's/your_line_pattern/#&/g' file > new_file
```

The & sign will take everything from the desired pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern in sed to apply commands only to lines that match a pattern is: `/pattern/cmd`.  So for this problem:

```
sed -e '/pattern/s/^/#/'
```